# java interfaces... quick questions

Tags: java, interface

can you tell me how this line works.... my OperatorFactory.get("add") is not doing anything. I'm not getting anything printed

```
ArithmeticOperator add = OperatorFactory.get ("add");
```

when I have the following:

```
interface ArithmeticOperator {

    // Returns the result of applying the operator to operands a and b.
    double operate (double a, double b);

    // Return a String that is the name of this operator.
    String printName ();
}


public class OperatorFactory implements ArithmeticOperator {



    public OperatorFactory(){

    }

    public static ArithmeticOperator get(String name){
        if(name.equals("add"))
                return new PlusOperator();
        else if(name.equals("sub"))
                return new SubOperator();
        else if(name.equals("mult"))
                return new MultOperator();
        else if(name.equals("div"))
                return new DivOperator();
        else
            return null;
    }

    public double operate(double a, double b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public String printName() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

---

```
public class PlusOperator extends OperatorFactory {



    public double operate(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;

    }

    public String printName() {
        return "Add";
    }

}




public class PlusOperator extends OperatorFactory {



    public double operate(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;

    }

    public String printName() {
        return "Add";
    }

}
```

Comment: why should u get something printed? You are just building it, not calling its **printName()** method..

Comment: "I am not getting anything printed". Well, the code doesn't do that anywhere. Where/how are you printing something then?

Comment: "I'm not getting anything printed" - Where and what are you trying to print? I don't see it in your code here

Comment: "I am not getting anything printed" - What they said

Comment: we really need "New Comment Posted" notifications :)

Comment: This smells more and more like homework or just a copypasted piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never call `add.printName()`, and you certainly don't output anything, so I'm not surprised that nothing is being printed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually tried printing the name?

```
ArithmeticOperator add = OperatorFactory.get ("add");
System.out.println(add.printName());
```

Also, the `PlusOperator` should implement `ArithmeticOperator` directly. The Factory should not implement `ArithmeticOperator`. This allows you to remove the operate and printName methods from the factory class.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like your get() method calls printName(), so it shouldn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `add.printName()` if you would like to output the operator's name.

Answer (score 0):

I won't repeat what everyone else already said - instead, here's a couple things to try in the future if you have this problem.

A good first sanity check for this problem is to run your code in a code coverage tool (I use EclEmma in Eclipse - I'm sure there's other good ones out there). This would show you that nothing is getting printed because the `printName()` method isn't being called.

Another way to debug this in Eclipse is by right clicking on your source, choosing "References > Project." This will show you from where the printName() method is being called, and you will see that it isn't being called because it isn't referenced from anywhere.